# How to parse a specific HTTP status error

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat, opensearch

I have a nginx-ingress-controller logs in the Elasticsearch that is not able to catch/parse HTTP error 503 (Service Unavailable) and come up with it in the "Status" field, but HTTP 200 and others work.

Elasticsearch discover - currently

[image: 1]

I have these the annotations already configured in the nginx-ingress-controller deployment:

```
annotations: 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.0.dissect.ignore_failure: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.0.dissect.target_prefix: dissect 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.0.dissect.tokenizer: '%{levelandtimestamp} %{pid} %{class} %{message}' 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.0.dissect.when.regexp.message: ^[IWEF][0-9]{4}.* 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.1.copy_fields.fields.0.from: dissect.levelandtimestamp 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.1.copy_fields.fields.0.to: dissect.timestamp 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.1.copy_fields.ignore_missing: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.field: dissect.timestamp 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.ignore_failure: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.target_prefix: dissect 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.tokenizer: '%{time_normilized}' 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.trim_chars: IWEF 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.2.dissect.trim_values: left 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.3.timestamp.field: dissect.time_normilized 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.3.timestamp.ignore_missing: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.3.timestamp.layouts: 0102 15:04:05.999 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.3.timestamp.when.has_fields: dissect.time_normilized 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.4.drop_fields.fields: message 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.4.drop_fields.ignore_missing: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.4.drop_fields.when.regexp.message: ^[IWEF][0-9]{4}.* 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.fields.0.from: dissect.message 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.fields.0.to: message 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.fields.1.from: dissect.class 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.fields.1.to: class 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.ignore_missing: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.5.rename.when.has_fields: dissect.message   
  co.elastic.logs/processors.6.add_fields.fields.level: INFO 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.6.add_fields.target: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.7.add_fields.fields.level: ERROR 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.7.add_fields.target: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.7.add_fields.when.contains.dissect.levelandtimestamp: E 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.8.add_fields.fields.level: WARN 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.8.add_fields.target: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.8.add_fields.when.contains.dissect.levelandtimestamp: W 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.9.add_fields.fields.level: FATAL 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.9.add_fields.target: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.9.add_fields.when.contains.dissect.levelandtimestamp: F 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.10.decode_json_fields.fields: message 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.10.decode_json_fields.max_depth: "1" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.10.decode_json_fields.overwrite_keys: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.10.decode_json_fields.target: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.11.timestamp.field: time 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.11.timestamp.layouts: "2006-01-02T15:04:05+00:00" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.11.timestamp.when.has_fields: time 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.12.dissect.field: request_query 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.12.dissect.ignore_failure: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.12.dissect.target_prefix: "" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.12.dissect.tokenizer: '%{request_method} %{request_uri} %{request_protocol}' 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.12.dissect.when.regexp.message: request_query 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.13.drop_fields.fields: message 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.13.drop_fields.ignore_missing: "true" 
  co.elastic.logs/processors.13.drop_fields.when.has_fields: request_query
```

Filebeat.yaml - ConfigMap:

```
Data
====
filebeat.yml:
----
http:
  enabled: true
  host: localhost
  port: 5066

filebeat.inputs:
- type: udp
  max_message_size: 10MiB
  host: "0.0.0.0:9999"
  fields:
    event_type: "vault-audit"
  fields_under_root: true
  processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        target: "vault"
        process_array: true
        overwrite_keys: false
        add_error_key: true
    - copy_fields:
        fields:
          - from: vault.response.data.username
            to: vault.response.datainfo.username
        fail_on_error: false
        ignore_missing: true
    - drop_fields:
        fields: ["vault.response.data"]
        ignore_missing: true
    - timestamp:
        field: vault.time
        layouts:
          - 'Y'

- type: tcp
  max_message_size: 10MiB
  host: "0.0.0.0:9000"
  fields:
    event_type: "vault-audit"
  fields_under_root: true
  processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        target: "vault"
        process_array: true
        overwrite_keys: false
        add_error_key: true
    - copy_fields:
        fields:
          - from: vault.response.data.username
            to: vault.response.datainfo.username
        fail_on_error: false
        ignore_missing: true
    - drop_fields:
        fields: ["vault.response.data"]
        ignore_missing: true
    - timestamp:
        field: vault.time
        layouts:
          - 'Y'

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config:
        type: container
        paths:
          - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.kubernetes.container.id}/*.log
processors:
  - add_fields:
      target: kubernetes
      fields:
        cluster.name: "k8s-dev"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        and:
          - contains:
              message: "DEBUG"
          - contains:
              message: "changes.SessionEntityWrapper"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        equals:
          class: "c.i.p.metrics.TelegrafMetricObserver"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        contains:
          message: "com.xxx"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        contains:
          message: "metrics.xxx.com"
  
  - drop_event:
      when:
        and:
          - equals:
              service: "CMC"
          - contains:
              exception.stacktrace: "org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        and:
          - equals:
              kubernetes.container.name: "selenoid"
          - contains:
              kubernetes.pod.name: "availability-tests"
  - drop_event:
      when:
        equals:
          kubernetes.labels.app: "time-nginx"

  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - rename:
      ignore_missing: true
      fail_on_error: false
      fields:
        - from: "kubernetes.labels.k8s-app"
          to: "service"
        - from: "kubernetes.labels.service"
          to: "service"
  - rename:
      fields:
        - from: "kubernetes.labels.tenant-alias"
          to: "tenant_alias"
      ignore_missing: true
      fail_on_error: false
      when:
        not:
          has_fields: ['tenant_alias']
  - rename:
      fields:
        - from: "kubernetes.labels.tenant-id"
          to: "tenant_id"
      ignore_missing: true
      fail_on_error: false
      when:
        not:
          has_fields: ['tenant_id']
  - script:
      lang: javascript
      id: lowercase
      source: >
        function process(event) {
            var level = event.Get("level");
            if(level != null) {
                event.Put("level", level.toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
  - drop_fields:
      fields:
        - dissect
        - ecs
        - input
        - ts
        - tsNs
        - stream
        - kubernetes.namespace_uid
        - kubernetes.namespace_labels
        - kubernetes.node.uid
        - kubernetes.node.hostname
        - kubernetes.node.labels
        - kubernetes.pod.uid
        - kubernetes.pod.ip
        - kubernetes.statefulset
        - kubernetes.replicaset
        - kubernetes.container.image
        - kubernetes.labels
        - container.id
      ignore_missing: true

logging.metrics.enabled: false
logging.json: true
logging.level: warning

output.kafka:
  version: 2.0.0
  codec.json:
    pretty: false
  #  escape_html: false
  client_id: "logshipper"
  hosts: ["kafka-cp.xxx.com:9094"]
  topic: "logging-kubernetes"
  topics:
    - topic: "kubernetes-audit"
      when.equals:
        event_type: "audit"
    - topic: "vault-audit"
      when.equals:
        event_type: "vault-audit"
  partition.round_robin:
    group_events: 10
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1e+06
  ssl.certificate_authorities: /tmp/ca.crt
```

How can I parse status error 503 into Elasticsearch Discover the same way as others?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the log format, more specifically in log-format-upstream in the nginx-ingress-controller configmap, some fields did not have "quote".
old:

```
 log-format-upstream: '{ "time": "$time_iso8601", "remote_addr": "$remote_addr",
    "x-forward-for": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for", "request_time": $request_time,
    "status": $status, "bytes_sent": $bytes_sent, "body_bytes_sent": $body_bytes_sent,
    "request_length": $request_length, "request_host": "$http_host", "request_query":
    "$request", "http_referrer": "$http_referer", "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent",
    "upstream_name": "$proxy_upstream_name", "upstream_addr": "$upstream_addr", "upstream_response_length":
    $upstream_response_length, "upstream_response_time": $upstream_response_time,
    "upstream_status": $upstream_status, "request_id": "$req_id" }'
```

new:

```
log-format-upstream: '{ "time": "$time_iso8601", "remote_addr": "$remote_addr",
"x-forward-for": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for", "request_time": "$request_time",
"status": "$status", "bytes_sent": "$bytes_sent", "body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent",
"request_length": "$request_length", "request_host": "$http_host", "request_query":
"$request", "http_referrer": "$http_referer", "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent",
"upstream_name": "$proxy_upstream_name", "upstream_addr": "$upstream_addr", "upstream_response_length":
"$upstream_response_length", "upstream_response_time": "$upstream_response_time",
"upstream_status": "$upstream_status", "request_id": "$req_id" }'
```